# How to connect the name in database to node in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Now I'm doing semi-conductor production simulation with Anylogic. I want to move transporter from node to node. These nodes have their own name. And i have a database with 3 columns. first columns name is "from", second is "to", and third is "volume". "From" means a node name list that the transporter has to visit first. "to" means a node name list that the transporter has to visit after visiting the "from". I want to get moved this transporter through "from" ~ "to". And there are nodes like "A_1", "A_2" ... in the default setting. I want to get moved the transporter or transporters follow the data from database. How to match the database's name data with existed node name?

```
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(sheet1).list();
        for (Tuple row : rows) {
            String fromNodeName = row.get(sheet1.from_db);
            String toNodeName = row.get(sheet1.to_db);

            Node locationFrom = nodeNameMap.get(fromNodeName);
            Node locationTo = nodeNameMap.get(toNodeName);

          
        }
```

This is my limitation Help me everyone

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to loop through all your nodes and check their names against the dbase string.

1. put all your nodes into a collection (select them, right-click -> "Create collection")
2. loop across the collection and check the name, i.e. something like below:

---

```
for (PointNode currNode : myNodeCollection) {
    if (currNode.getName().equals(myDbaseString)) {
        // store as the start/end point
    }
}
```